# Prevent users from typing and clicking in MS Word Add-in

Tags: ms-word, vsto, add-in

I am writting a MS Word Add-in, I create a button to run a long time work with text. My work requires that during the time it is excuted, no change can be made by user ( typing, clicking, deleting ...) When this work is completed, user can type and click as usual.
I have used

```
this.Application.Options.AllowClickAndTypeMouse = false;
```

However, this doesn't work.
Who can help me!

Comment: I would suggest to hide the window or application when macro is running. Alternatively you should show at the top of application Add-in form with information which will also block document edition.

Answer (score 0):

First, your approach is wrong. The Click and Type is Word functionality and has nothing to do with disabling user Mouse clicks
(For more information about Click and Type refer to [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/about-click-and-type-HP005257639.aspx)).

Now for your question, here is one approach I would suggest:

If the user is not able to do any action, I would expect an appropriate message, so my idea is to create a modal form by using:

```
myForm.ShowDialog();
```

It should do the job and block the active document until it get closed.
I would also add a nice progress bar and "Close" button which you will enable when work has done.